# Kotlin : update one column with viewmodel in Room

Tags: kotlin, android-room

I using room database on kotlin. and I want to update or change just one row and specify column of
that rows. i write query in my DAO but I don't know how  must be used. I have one repository and one viewmodel that I used. read all data work fine. i want to when user clicked on my button, value of **fav** column  is changed and saved in my room database. how must be changed Dao, repository and viewmodel in my project for this? thank u

EDIT : i updated my project code for more help :

Detail_ViewModel :

```
fun viewmodelupdate(id:Int , fav:String) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

    val viewomodel_update_dao = Detail_Database.getDatabase(context,viewModelScope).detail_dao()
    var myrepository = Detail_Repository(viewomodel_update_dao)
    myrepository.reposupdate(id,fav)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this issue with adding below code in my main activity to pass data to viemodel :

```
 collpsViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(Detail_ViewModel::class.java)
        collpsViewModel.viewmodelupdate(profile_id.toInt(),"1")
```